# Newrelic infra agent on AKS Node pool

Tags: azure-aks, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I would like to install and configure newrelic infra agent on AKS node pool. I have explored links but couldn't find any helpful. Could anyone help to start working on this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my solution via deamonset and configmap with nodeinstaller. Below links really helped me but not through terraform as AKS won't support custom script to automate via terraform.(Hi can I have a custom script to be executed in AKS node group?)

Reference links: https://medium.com/@patnaikshekhar/initialize-your-aks-nodes-with-daemonsets-679fa81fd20e

https://github.com/patnaikshekhar/AKSNodeInstaller

daemonset.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: node-installer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: installer
  namespace: node-installer
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      job: installer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        job: installer
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - image: patnaikshekhar/node-installer:1.3
        name: installer
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: install-script
          mountPath: /tmp
        - name: host-mount
          mountPath: /host
      volumes:
      - name: install-script
        configMap:
          name: sample-installer-config
      - name: host-mount
        hostPath:
          path: /tmp/install
```

sampleconfigmap.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sample-installer-config
  namespace: node-installer
data:
  install.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash

    # install newrelic-infra
    echo "license_key: #{NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY}#" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
    echo "enabled: #{NEW_RELIC_INFRA_AGENT_ENABLED}#" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml

    curl -s https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/gpg/newrelic-infra.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
    printf "deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt bionic main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infra.list
    sudo apt-get update -y
    sudo apt-get install newrelic-infra -y
    sudo systemctl status newrelic-infra
    echo "Newrelic infra agent installation is done"

    # enable log forwarding
    echo "logs:" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml
    echo "  - name: log-files-in-folder" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml
    echo "    file: /var/log/onefc/*/*.newrelic.log" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml
    echo "    max_line_kb: 256" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml
# trigger log forwarding
sudo newrelic-infra-ctl
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/newrelic/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/newrelic-infrastructure) is the helm chart that deploys the New Relic Infrastructure agent as a Daemonset.

Comment: Philip and dharman, thanks for sharing the links and much appreciated.

Comment: Is there is any direct way to install New relic infra agent on VMSS only during node pool scaling. So that it will be really so helpful.Much appreciated for your help.

Comment: Any update please. Really its required urgently.

Comment: i would not recommend installing the agent directly on the nodes bcs during update and auto-scaling nodes get replaced and then you have to install the agent over and over again. The Helm-Chart with the Daemonset runs in privileged mode and with hostnetwork so i think it is a good way to use the agent and to always have it deployed on every node after update or auto-scaling lifecycle.

Comment: Much appreciated your help here. May I know when this helm chart is published and made public from Newrelic? When I checked an year ago I couldn't see this helm chart.

Comment: seems it was imported May 2020 : https://github.com/newrelic/helm-charts/commits/master?after=c05d1e925a6969c16bcbc59f08c17b409682075d+34&branch=master&path%5B%5D=charts&path%5B%5D=newrelic-infrastructure

Comment: Now,my client is looking for only few metrics only as the above helm chart approach was giving all the metrics but client specifically looking for host machine metrics only as other metrics they are monitoring through log analytics and other tools.So now I am trying to install the new relic extension in VM or VMSS and its showing the name in newrelic but not showing any data. Could you please check my screenshot and let me know why its not giving the results in new relic.

Comment: For VM I could see in new relic where as for VMSS if I install new relic extension I don't even see that name in newrelic.The following link says that we can get alerts using VM and VMSS but I don't see any VMSS metrics in newrelic.
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/install-infrastructure-agent/linux-installation/azure-extensions-infrastructure

Comment: I have attached screenshot of VMSS in azure where I installed extension for new relic but its not visible or showing anything in new relic but for VM its showing the metrics in new relic.

Comment: If possible could you please share any custom data or user data via scripts if we can install newrelic infra in VMSS.This is my client requirement.